# Python Pandas Filter

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter specific rows with python-pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter=',', header=None,engine='python', usecols=range(0, 7), error_bad_lines=False)

df = df.drop(df.index[9:86579]) 

df = df[df[[0,1]].apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('TestString1', case=False).any(), axis=1)] 

df.to_csv("yourcsv.csv", index=False, header=None)#
```

Now how can I set a starting row? Because my rows "0-10" consist information and I want to start searching by keyword from row 11. But how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.iloc[11:].to_csv("yourcsv.csv", index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: Thanks. It work's but only after this line:
df = df[df[[0,2]].apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('CVE-2016', case=False).any(), axis=1)] 
But I want to exclude the lines befor searching/matching strings

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to drop rows and "see" only from a certain row your dataframe you can use ILOC function:

```
df["column name"].iloc[11:].apply(function)
```

This example you get from 11th row until last one and apply your function.

> DataFrame.iloc
>
> Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position.
>
> Allowed inputs are:
>
> An integer, e.g. 5.
>
> - A list or array of integers, e.g. [4, 3, 0].
> - A slice object with ints, e.g. 1:7.
> - A boolean array.
> - A callable function with one argument (the calling Series, DataFrame or Panel) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the above)

`.iloc[]` is primarily integer position based (from `0` to `length-1` of the axis), but may also be used with a boolean array.

Comment: Don't work how I want.

This here works for me:
# Exclude first 10 rows 
df1=pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:10])

# Match word in column 0 and 2 and show me the rows 
df2 = df[df[[0,2]].apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('CVE-2016', case=False).any(), axis=1)]

# Combine excluded and filtered rows
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "Because my rows "0-10" consist information and I want to start searching by keyword from row 11".

If you mean that you need the first 10 rows to be used as a condition for making your filter working afterwards, then you can iterate by row and use np.where.

If this is not the case, than I believe the other two answers (John, Rafael) already solved your problem so you can vote them up.